# Mesh details doesn't show up in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, blender

I'm new to three.js so I don't know exactly what is going on. I exported a model from blender using Three.js exporter and it seems slightly darker than it is on blender when I use MeshFaceMaterial

[image: Can't see tires details or backlights]

but when I use MeshLambertMaterial or MeshPhongMaterial it seems normal, except the mesh is all white. You can see all the details such as the tires.

[image: Tires and backlights details are visible, but mesh is all white]

Anyone can tell me what is wrong? Already played around with types of lights and positions, but no success. Code is below. Can this be a light position problem? Why is the model all white with MeshLambertMaterial?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>three.js JSON Loader</title>
        <style>
            body{ background-color: grey; }
            canvas{ background-color: white; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body></body>       
    <script src="three.js-master/build/three.js"></script>
    <script>        
    var camera, scene, renderer, mesh, loader;

    init();

    function init() {

        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000 );
        camera.position.z = 100;
        camera.position.y = 20;

        scene = new THREE.Scene();

        var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x555555);
        scene.add(ambientLight);

        var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
        directionalLight.position.set(1, 1, 1).normalize();
        scene.add(directionalLight);

        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth - 25, window.innerHeight - 25 );

        document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );       

        loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();

        loader.load( "TRATOR.js", function( geometry, materials ) {
            mesh = new THREE.Mesh( 
                geometry, 
                //new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materials )
                new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( materials )
            );
            mesh.overdraw = true;
            mesh.scale.set( 10, 10, 10 );
            mesh.position.x = 0;
            mesh.position.y = 0;
            mesh.position.z = 0;

            mesh.rotation.y =  45 * Math.PI / 180 - 0.2;

            scene.add( mesh );

            //animar apenas depois de carregar o modelo
            animate();
        } );
    }

    function animate() {

        requestAnimationFrame( animate );

        if(mesh != undefined) {
            //mesh.rotation.x += 0.005;
            //mesh.rotation.z += 0.005;
            //mesh.rotation.y += 0.005; //comentado provisoriamente
        }

        renderer.render( scene, camera );
    }

    window.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
        var key = event.which ? event.which : event.keyCode;
        switch(key) {
            case 39:
                mesh.rotation.y += 0.1;
                break;
            case 37:
                mesh.rotation.y -= 0.1;
                break;
            case 40:
                mesh.rotation.x += 0.1;
                break;
            case 38:
                mesh.rotation.x -= 0.1;
                break;
        }
    }, false);
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried `var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff);` together with `var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color:0xff0000, transparent:true, opacity:1.0 } );` ?

Comment: I did know, however it loads the mesh with a single color. I want the object to be loaded with the original colors of the blender model.

Comment: You need to understand what the parameters of the materials in the `materials` array mean, set them to reasonable values, and use `MeshFaceMaterials( materials )`.